# Одноразовая регистрация пользователя Android

Tags: java, android

Планируется сделать одноразовую регистрацию:
Когда приложение запускается в первый раз на устройстве, открывается окно с регистрацией (логин, пароль, без подтверждений по почте или телефону. только логин и пароль)
В дальнейшем (следующая активность) к пользователю будут обращаться по его логину.
Как сделать так, чтобы при последующем запуске приложение уже открывалось со второй (главной) активности (которая следует после окна регистрации), то есть снова не спрашивать логин и пароль и уже снова  не регистрироваться? Приложение так сказать "запомнило" кто такой его пользователь. То есть он открывает приложение и уже к нему обращается по его логину (который он один раз указал при регистрации с паролем)?
**P.S. приложение на Java под Android**

Answer (score 1):

Используй привязку к ID устройства, сохраняй её при первой регистрации, и далее выполняй проверку при запуске

```
deviceID = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть разные способы, расскажу про самый распространенный, как это обычно делается с помощью JWT токенов (просто при регистрации сервер сразу сгенерит токен и отдаст его приложению, чтобы оно после регистрации запомнило юзера, а не при регистрации + логине).

1. При вводе логина и пароля, приложение отправляет их на сервер.
2. Сервер проверяет данные и если они корректны, генерирует токены, которые по сути являются доказательством аутентификации для последующих подключений приложения.
3. Сервер отправляет эти токены приложению (их два, access-токен, который является по сути ключом, который авторизует приложение (время действия истекает быстро), и refresh-токен, который нужен для того, чтобы получить новый access-токен (время действия дольше).
4. Приложение сохраняет токены и входит с помощью access-токена.

При последующей авторизации приложение берет имеющийся access-токен и авторизуется. Если access-токен устарел, использует refresh-токен, чтобы получить новый access-токен. Если refresh-токен устарел, то приложение просит заново ввести логин и пароль.

Это работает примерно так, пароли никогда не хранятся на стороне приложения, только токены, время действия которых определяет сервер.

Если интересно подробнее почитать про JWT, вот [ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token).